# Using Visual Studio 2015 Shell to open website, having error message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: url

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I received the following error message (Value cannot be null. Parameter name: url) when I am trying to open a website using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell(Integrated).

An image of the error message:
[image: An image of the error message]

It used to work when I do the same thing with VS2012 Shell.

I can't load the website and also create a new website either. The machine I'm working on is a vpc that does not have internet connection for security purpose.

I suspect this could be an IDE issue but I just wonder if this is a project configuration issue that anyone here might have seen before I ask for permission to reinstall the IDE and cause other people's work getting delayed on this machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar message box using Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop to try to upgrade an older .NET executable project. When I opened the project, it wouldn't expand in the Solution Explorer. Instead, it said it needed to be upgraded. (I could open the project XML directly, but I'm not skilled enough to work with that directly.) When I tried to Build the project, it would prompt me to perform a one way upgrade of the project (referencing [additional documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.ReviewProjectAndSolutionChangesDialog.Upgrade)&rd=true). I agreed, and it seemed to start, but then it failed with an error like this question references.

Searching for this or a related error, I came upon [a similar question involving `pSrcNativeVariant`](http://ebanshi.cc/questions/1770503/error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-psrcnativevariant-in-vs2010).

Their suggested answers were:

> I encountered exactly the same problem. After trying many things, I
>   found this problem could be simply solved by just running the visual
>   studio in the administration mode once. Under the admin mode, run the
>   nsight debugger, then the problem is solved. Admin mode is not
>   required later. At least this works for me, good luck to you.
>
> Added on May 12, 2014: This problem happened again today. This time I
>   solved it by switching the platform from Win32 to X64 then switch back
>
> Added on May 22, 2014: It happens again and everything I tried before
>   did not work this time. Finally it is solved in this way: I fixed this
>   by deleting the visual studio solution user options file (.suo).

I don't know what the "nsight debugger" is, but I first tried running as administrator (with a few restarts of the IDE), but that didn't work.

I then tried deleting the .suo file, but that also didn't work.

Or at least, I don't think I did. After several tries, running as Administrator, it finally worked and upgraded the projected, providing visibility in the solution explorer. Unfortunately I don't recall if I did anything different; sorry.

I subsequently loaded the project outside of Administrator mode and it continued to work.

These are the substantive changes the upgrade process made, in case they are helpful...

[ProjectName]\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:

```
 - '     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.42
 + '     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
```

[ProjectName]\My Project\Resources.Designer.vb:

```
 - '     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.42
 + '     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
```

...

```
 -     <Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "2.0.0.0"),  _
 +     <Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0"),  _
```

[ProjectName]\My Project\Settings.Designer.vb:

```
 - '     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.42
 + '     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000


 -      Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "8.0.0.0"),  _
 +      Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "14.0.0.0"),  _


 -         Private Shared defaultInstance As MySettings = CType(Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(New MySettings),MySettings)
 +         Private Shared defaultInstance As MySettings = CType(Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(New MySettings()),MySettings)
```

[ProjectName][ProjectName].vbproj:

```
 - <Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 + <Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="14.0">
```

...

```
 +     <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
 +     <FileUpgradeFlags>
 +     </FileUpgradeFlags>
 +     <UpgradeBackupLocation>
 +     </UpgradeBackupLocation>
 +     <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
```

...

```
 -     <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
 +     <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022,42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
```

...

```
 -     <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
 +     <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022,42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
```